# BlackBerry SQLite: Attach one SQLite database to another

Tags: java, sqlite, blackberry

I'm trying to attach one SQLite database to another on BlackBerry using SQLite [ATTACH DATABASE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) command.

```
Database d1, d2;
Statement st;

URI dbURI1 = URI.create("file:///SDCard/Databases/SQLiteExample/MyTestDatabase1.db") 
if (DatabaseFactory.exists(dbURI1)) {
    d1 = DatabaseFactory.open(dbURI1);
} else {
    d1 = DatabaseFactory.create(dbURI1);
    st = d1.createStatement("CREATE TABLE 'People' ( 'Name' TEXT, 'Age' INTEGER )");

    st.prepare();
    st.execute();
    st.close();
}

URI dbURI2 = URI.create("file:///SDCard/Databases/SQLiteExample/MyTestDatabase2.db");
if (DatabaseFactory.exists(dbURI2)) {
    d2 = DatabaseFactory.open(dbURI2);
} else {
    d2 = DatabaseFactory.create(dbURI2);
    st = d2.createStatement("CREATE TABLE 'People2' ('Name2' TEXT, 'Age2' INTEGER )");

    st.prepare();
    st.execute();
    st.close();
    d2.close();
}

st = d1.createStatement("ATTACH DATABASE '/SDCard/Databases/SQLiteExample/MyTestDatabase2.db' as SECOND_TABLE");
st.prepare(); //THROWS AN EXCEPTION "SQL logic error or missing database"
st.execute();
st.close();
```

I'm getting an Exception `ATTACH DATABASE /SDCard/Databases/SQLiteExample/MyTestDatabase2.db' as SECOND_TABLE: SQLlogic error or missing database`
when it tries to prepare statement for "Attach Database" command.

Is it possible to use `ATTACH DATABASE` command with BlackBerry SQLite API?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the BlackBerry implementation of SQLite does not support ATTACH DATABASE. See the BlackBerry documentation "[Working with SQLite databases](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17952/Working_with_SQLite_databases_1219779_11.jsp)" for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

RIM has added `Attach/Detach Database` commands to their BlackBerry OS 7.0 API:
[BlackBerry 7.0 API Docs](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/database/Database.html#attach%28net.rim.device.api.io.URI,%20java.lang.String,%20net.rim.device.api.database.DatabaseSecurityOptions%29)